# how to call a stored procedure from a block Select a MyBatis 2.3.5

Tags: java, select, call, procedure, ibatis

my select block is

```
<select id="getItemsCount" resultClass="java.math.BigDecimal" parameterClass="com.item.SimlpeListFilter">
    SELECT COUNT(1) FROM T_SYSTEM.T_ITEM_LIST
    <include refid="itemListFilter"/>
</select>
```

in itemListFilte have procedure calls, adding there {call anyProcedure} is not appropriate. Filter dynamic forms. May contain procedures. Which does not cause a query